# How to execute MS SQL PLSQL script multiple time from LINUX Box

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, shell, scheduled-tasks

I've PL SQL Block ; which needs to be executed multiple times in a day. 
This Block updates data in Microsoft SQL Server.

Is there any way; I can connect MS SQL Database from Linux box and schedule query execution multiple times in a day?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use PL/SQL - do you mean T-SQL?

Comment: And assuming you do mean T-SQL, the answer is yes - you can use JDBC drivers for SQL Server to do this.  But this question as stated is unclear/too broad...

Comment: Sorry but voting to close this Q as too broad.. Search here for `[bash] crontab script MS-SQL` (change MS-SQL as needed to get DB specific examples). (crontab allows you to schedule a script to run as often or as seldom as you need). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script and then use crontab to schedule the task to run as often as you would like.

To Edit: `crontab -e`
While in crontab it works just like vi. So to edit, press `i`. To stop editing press the `Esc`. To save and quit type `:wq`.

To view: `crontab -l`

for questions: `man crontab`

crontab example:`54 14 * * * myJob` This will run "myJob" at 2:54pm, daily.

You could also use something like this to help you make the schedule for crontab http://crontab-generator.org/